# Proof verification affine curve not isomorphic to plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, algebraic-curves, irreducible-polynomials, affine-geometry

I'm trying to prove that the affine curve $X\subset\mathbb{A}^3$ given by
$\alpha:\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^3$, $t\mapsto(t^3,t^4,t^5)$, is not isomorphic to a plane curve.

Here is what I've done: it is enough to show that the dimension of $\mathcal{O}_{X,(0,0,0)}$ is greater than 2. As $\mathcal{O}_{X,(0,0,0)}=k[X]_{\mathfrak{m_0}}$, where $k[X]$ is the coordinate ring $k[x,y,z]/(x^4-y^3,x^5-z^3)$ and $\mathfrak{m_0}=\{f\in k[X]:f(0,0,0)=0\}=(\bar x,\bar y,\bar z)$, and as the prime ideals in $k[X]_{\mathfrak{m_0}}$ are in bijective correspondence with the prime ideals in $k[X]$ which are contained in $\mathfrak{m_0}$, it will suffice to find a chain of length 4 of prime ideals between $(0)$ and $\mathfrak{m_0}$ in $k[X]$. I've thought of $(0)\subset (\bar x)\subset (\bar x,\bar y)\subset \mathfrak{m_0}$.

Could somebody point out some possible flaw? I've never got along with irreducibility issues so my apologizes for every stupid confussion.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is another possible direction of attack (not sure if it works). We know two affine varieties are isomorphic iff their coordinate rings are isomorphic as $k$-algebras. If $X$ were isomophic to an affine plane curve $Y$, then the coordinate ring of $Y$ would be generated as a $k$-algebra by two elements. Is that possible for $k[X]$?

Comment: What if you look at the tangent space there?

Comment: @hwong557 That is helpful! :) I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Hoot I know that can be proved used tangent space. Just wanted ti know if can be proved this way. I've looked around for quite a while and haven't find a single example of such a proof without tangent space.

Comment: Reading more carefully I don't see how this is going to work. If $X$ is an irreducible variety of dimension $n$ then the local rings at the (closed) points are all $n$-dimensional. See Hartshorne I.3.2 for a proof.

Comment: @Hoot I meant that can be proved that not every affine curve is isomorphic to a plane curve using the tangent space. Dont know if this example would work, neither if this approach would. There was something about it bugging me. I'll see it!

Comment: @John Two questions: do you mean that $X$ is not a plane curve in $\mathbb{A}^3$?, are you sure that you had find a chain of prime ideals in $k[X]_{\mathfrak{m}_0}$?

Comment: @Armandoj18eos I'm no expert, not even remotely close in this field, but I meant that $X$ is not isomorphic to a plane curve, i.e. to a curve in $\mathbb{A}^2$. I've showed it by proving that the tangent space at (0,0,0) has dimension 3. And to your second question, no I'm not sure. Just was an attempt of proof

Comment: $\left(\overline{x}\right)$ is not a prime ideal, because $\left(\overline{x}\right)\ni\overline{x}^4=\overline{y}^3$ and $\overline{y}\not\in\left(\overline{x}\right)$; analogously $\left(\overline{x},\overline{y}\right)$ is not a prime ideal.

Comment: @Armandoj18eos I was afraid so, It was just an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I skip the proof that $(0)\subsetneqq(x^4-y^3)\subsetneqq(x^4-y^3,x^5-z^3)\subsetneqq(x,y,z)$ is a maximal chain of prime ideals in $k[x,y,z]$.

By theory, one knows that $\left(\overline0\right)=\left(\overline{x}^4-\overline{y}^3,\overline{x}^5-\overline{z}^3\right)\subsetneqq\left(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z}\right)$ is a chain of prime ideals in $k[X]$; in particular:

- $\dim_{Krull}k[X]\geq1$;
- $\left(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z}\right)=\overline{\mathfrak{m}}$ is a maximal ideal of $k[X]$.

Because $X$ is the image via a continuous and surjective map of $\mathbb{A}^1$, that is of an irreducible space of Krull dimension $1$, then $\dim_{Krull}X\leq1$; by previous statement: $\dim_{Krull}k[X]=1$.

At this point, by previous reasoning, one can easy to prove that $\dim_{Krull}k[X]_{\overline{\mathfrak{m}}}=1$; but $\overline{\mathfrak{m}}$ in $k[X]_{\overline{\mathfrak{m}}}$ has three ($3$) generators, indeed $\overline{x}\notin\left(\overline{y},\overline{z}\right)$ and so on; in other words, $k[X]_{\overline{\mathfrak{m}}}$ is not a regular local ring.

By definition $O=(0,0,0)$ is not a regular point of $X$; the Zariski cotangent space of $X$ at $O$ is
\begin{equation*}
\left(T_OX\right)^{\vee}=\overline{\mathfrak{m}}_{\displaystyle/\overline{\mathfrak{m}}^2}=\left(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z}\right)_{\displaystyle/\left(\overline{x}^2,\overline{xy},\overline{y}^2,\overline{yz},\overline{z}^2,\overline{zx}\right)}\cong\left\{\left[a\overline{x}+b\overline{y}+c\overline{z}\in k[X]_{\mathfrak{m}}\right]\mid a,b,c\in k[X]_{\mathfrak{m}}\setminus\overline{\mathfrak{m}}\right\}
\end{equation*}
and its dimension over $\kappa(O)=k$ is $3$; in the same way, one can compute the Zariski cotangent space of $\mathbb{A}^3$ at $O$.

Considering the canonical projection $\pi:k[x,y,z]\to k[X]$, passing to the localization at $\mathfrak{m}$, again $\varpi=\pi_{\mathfrak{m}}:k[x,y,z]_{\mathfrak{m}}\to k[X]_{\overline{\mathfrak{m}}}$ is a surjective morphism of local rings; so $\varpi(\mathfrak{m})=\overline{\mathfrak{m}}$. In this way, one can consider the $k$-linear surjective morphism
\begin{equation*}
\left(d_Oi\right)^{\vee}:[a]\in\left(T_{i(O)}\mathbb{A}^3\right)^{\vee}\cong k^3\to[\varpi(a)]\in\left(T_OX\right)^{\vee}\cong k^3,
\end{equation*}
where $i$ is the inclusion of $X$ in $\mathbb{A}^3$.

Up to regular isomorphisms, if there exists an inclusion $j$ of $X$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$ then one can find a $k$-linear surjective morphism $\left(d_Oj\right)^{\vee}$ from $k^2$ onto $k^3$: this is a contraddition and so $X$ is not a plane curve.

Comment: About the suggested edit, when I say a plane curve I mean a curve in $\mathbb{A}^2$. Now, about the answer, I think the second proof is not actually; I wasn't trying to prove that $X$ is contained in some plane, I was trying to prove that It can't be isomorphic to a plane curve (a curve contained in a  plane if you like). Againg, I am no expert at all here but I think they're not the same thing. Don't know if this confussion affects the first proof but if the heart of it is that the tangent space at 0 has dimension 3, why not just calculate the tangent space?

Comment: @Jonh Sorry me, I was misread your question; I had correct and clarify my answer. I am disposable for other explanation.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but I still can't see the argument behind your answer. If the crucial point that solves the question is that the tangent space has dimension 3, why not just compute the tangent space? I think I have solved it this way. I wasn't going to post my answer but for the sake of having some criteria and since I have no idea of what answer is better, I will and in a day or so I will accept the answer with more upvotes. I actually don't care about points, and I apologize if I just don't know enough to notice that the answer is fine, hope this is fair enough

Comment: I had improve my answer in a way that you can see as I use the fact that the dimension $3$ of the (co)tangent space of $X$ at $O$ impedes the existence of a regular isomorphism between $X$ and a plane curve.

Comment: All right, I see it now. Thank u for your consideration and patience, algebraic geometry is really not my thing.

Comment: Don't worry: at the begin, I am bored from algebraic geometry; but today I am enthusiastic (because there exists the scheme theory). If you permet me, I suggest you Hulek - _Elementary Algebraic Geometry_, Mumford's _Red Book_ (only chapter 1) and Mumford - _Algebraic Geometry, I; Complex Projective Varieties_.

Answer (score 0):

Proof that $X$ is not isomorphic to a plane curve using tangent space:

It is enough to find a point $p\in X$ such that the tangent space $T_p(X)$ has dimension $>2$ (as a vector space).
Writing $X=\{(t_1,t_2,t_3)\in\mathbb{A}^3:t_1^4-t_2^3=t_1^5-t_3^3=0\}$ we can compute the tangent space at $p$ as
$$
T_p(X)=\{v=(t_1,t_2,t_3)\in k^3:L_1(v)=L_2(v)=0\},
$$
where $L_1(v)=\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\partial(t_1^4-t_2^3)}{\partial t_i}(p)\cdot t_i,$ $L_2(v)=\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\partial(t_1^5-t_3^3)}{\partial t_i}(p)\cdot t_i$.
Choosing $p=0$ we get that $L_0(v)\equiv L_1(v)\equiv 0$, so $T_0(C)=k^3$. In particular
$$
\text{dim}_kT_0(X)=3>2.
$$